# Why is there an error: expected string or bytes-like object

Tags: python-3.x, tkinter

I was making an youtube converter with tkinter. I have started using it like 2 weeks ago and i get this error. But i dont know how to get it work. I tried looking on internet but I couldn't find a proper solution. Can anyone help me?
The code I have:

```
from tkinter import *
import youtube_dl
from youtube_dl import YoutubeDL

root = Tk()
root.title('Oden Youtube to MP3 converter')
root.iconbitmap('favicon.ico')
root.geometry('400x300+0+0')
title = Label(root, text='Musicdownloader V1.0')
title.pack()

topFrame = Frame(root)
topFrame.pack()
bottomFrame = Frame(root)
bottomFrame.pack(side=BOTTOM)

e = Entry(topFrame, width=50)
e.pack(side=TOP)
yturl = e.get

def url():
    label1 = Label(root, text=f'url: {e.get()}')
    label1.pack()
    label2 = Label(root, text='This can take 5-15 seconds')
    label2.pack()
    ydl_opts = {
    'format': 'bestaudio/best',
    'postprocessors': [{
        'key': 'FFmpegExtractAudio',
        'preferredcodec': 'mp3',
        'preferredquality': '192',
        }],
    }
    with youtube_dl.YoutubeDL(ydl_opts) as ydl:
        ydl.download([yturl])

button1 = Button(topFrame, text='Convert', fg='black', command=url)
button1.pack()
quitbutton = Button(bottomFrame, text='Quit', fg='black', command=root.quit)
quitbutton.pack()

root.mainloop()
```

The error:

```
Exception in Tkinter callback
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\Guido\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\lib\tkinter\__init__.py", line 1883, in __call__
    return self.func(*args)
  File "c:/Users/Guido/Desktop/yeet/overig/coding/windows apps/Musicdownloaderv2.0/downloader.py", line 38, in url
    ydl.download([yturl])
  File "C:\Users\Guido\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\lib\site-packages\youtube_dl\YoutubeDL.py", line 2018, in download
    res = self.extract_info(
  File "C:\Users\Guido\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\lib\site-packages\youtube_dl\YoutubeDL.py", line 788, in extract_info
    if not ie.suitable(url):
  File "C:\Users\Guido\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\lib\site-packages\youtube_dl\extractor\common.py", line 411, in suitable
    return cls._VALID_URL_RE.match(url) is not None
TypeError: expected string or bytes-like object
```

Comment: I think should `e.get` should be `e.get()`

Comment: then i get this error: ```youtube_dl.utils.DownloadError: ERROR: '' is not a valid URL. Set --default-search "ytsearch" (or run  youtube-dl "ytsearch:" ) to search YouTube```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to change this line:

```py
ydl.download([yturl])
```

to

```py
ydl.download([e.get()])
```

You can't use your `yturl` variable like you are now as it will always be an empty string.

Comment: I litterally found out a second ago xD. But thanks. (-: